# How to change the FlatStyle MouseDownBackColor of several buttons being in a WinForms Panel?

Tags: c#

I need to parse controls in a panel to update some buttons.
I don't understand how to access this to change a buttons flat style mouse down back colour

`public Color MouseDownBackColor {get; set;}`

I know I can use `this.button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor =` but in this case I have the button being accessed from a pannel as a var and it can't
be access it this way.

**Update:**

```
foreach (Control control in button_panel.Controls)
{
    if (control is Button)
    {
       var button = (Button)control;
       button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlatStyle` property of buttons must be set to `FlatStyle.Flat` to work.

You can use type casting (*unboxing*) towards `Button` after the type check:

```
foreach (Control control in button_panel.Controls)
{
    if (control is Button)
    {
      var button = (Button)control;
      button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
      button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

You can also write this using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

button_panel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(button =>
{
  button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Yellow;
});
```

Comment: The button already has this set, what I am struggling with is accessing this from within form1.cs
I am using a instance of the button and can't access it directly.

`foreach (Control b in button_panel.Controls)
{
if (b is Button)
{//change colour here }} `

Comment: I don't understand. Is that solve the problem: `foreach (Control control in button_panel.Controls) { if (control is Button) { var button = (Button)control; button.FlatStyle=... }}` ?

Comment: I have updated the question to show what I came to.